# ArrayList of ints to smaller array of ints

Tags: java, arrays

Im building my first program. The idea is to read a list of questions from a file and then allow the user to select a number of random questions to get asked.  For instance the program will have 30 questions.  However the user may only want to practice 5 questions at a time.  I have reached my first real hang up.

Im writing a method that will allow the user to input how many questions they want asked.  The method will output an in array of x random numbers that do not exceed the amount of questions.  I then plan to use that array to call the actual questions from another method that I have already successfully built.

Here is the code for the method

```
public int [] ranQuest(int numQs, int totalQs) {

    int [] numberQs = new int [numQs];
    int maxNum = totalQs;

    ArrayList<Integer> allQs = new ArrayList(); 

    for (int x = 0; x < maxNum; x++) {
        allQs.add(x);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(allQs);

    for(int x = 0; x < numberQs.length; x++) {    
       numberQs[x] = allQs.get(x);
    }

    return numberQs;
}
```

I have commented out my troubleshooting print lines.
Here is my test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GameLoad gl = new GameLoad();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userAns = null;
    Random randInt = new Random();
    QuestGen questGen = new QuestGen();

    int [] quests = questGen.ranQuest(4, 10);

    for (int quest : quests) {
        System.out.println(quests[quest]);
    }
}
```

When I run the code for inputs of 3, 3 or 4, 4 it sudo works.  I do not get a outofbounds exception error but the numbers are not in the order I expect. When I run the code for 3, 10 or 5, 30...I get an outofbounds exception error that dumfounds me because I think my for loop is good.

I have done a lot of searching and it seems like I may have a problem trying to convert Integers to ints, or maybe my for loop to populate the int array is not right.  Is there a way or better way then the path Im on to take an array of X ints populated in order mix those up, and then populate a new smaller array?

Thanks in advance
Jojo

Comment: A tip: never declare a list of type `ArrayList`, use `List` instead, which is the class that `ArrayList` implements. This will allow you to easily switch between different implementations (another popular `List` implementation is `LinkedList`). So just go `List<T> myList = new ArrayList();`

Comment: You should check foreach and for difference to have less problems in future Foreach : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work
For :
https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-for-loop-work-in-Java Hope it will help you resolve your problem !

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I had seen this done in other places and was not sure what was going on.  Your tip cleared it up.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int quest : quests) {
    System.out.println(quests[quest]);
}
```

change it to

```
for (int quest : quests) {
    System.out.println(quest);
}
```

Right now if your array contains for example the elements 10, 11 and 12
you are asking for the values of `quests[10]`, `quests[11]` and `quests[12]` which are obviously not defined since the array has only three elements.

Comment: Man super frustrating.  The whole time I was searching for an error in my method and it turns out my test was what was killing me.  Thanks for the quick fix.